# ASP.NET MVC 2 "RequiresRole" attribute does not work

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a ASP.NET MVC 2 web application. So far, I managed to define access rules for every controller function, using "RequiresRole" attribute.

Suddenly, this way of defining access rules stopped working (now every user can invoke any of the controller methods). :S. I tried debugging, and it seems that user-roles are correct. I tried reviewing web.config, but did not find anything suspicious.

Don't know what else could be the problem.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RequresRoleAttribute` is intended for use on WCF domain data services, not MVC controllers. I believe the attribute you should use is `AuthorizeAttribute`, setting the `Roles` parameter.